# About a modification in logistic (or Verhulst) differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, biology

I have found the following question about growth population models.

Let us consider the following situtation:

In a certain habitat we have two populations: birds and worms. It is known that the growth of worms population, in absence of birds, is modeled by the diferential equation: $$w'(t)=0.3w\left(1-\frac{w}{1000}\right).$$
Now, if worms are hunted by birds following a rate (r=0.1) which is proportional to number of worms:

a) Modify the initial equation to collect this phenomenon.

b) Under the above conditions, suggest a modification of the equation, having in count that birds stop hunting when the number of hunted worms is equal to $275$.

**My attempt**

a)I think that it can be a good idea consider $$w'(t)=0.3w\left(1-\frac{w}{1000}\right)-0.1w(t).$$
b)This is the part where I found a bigger problem. I don't know exactly how to include a term which describes this phenomenon. Could someone help me?

Comment: Discontinuous changes can sometimes be modeled by the unit ramp function.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Could you be more specific?

Comment: Multiply the last term with $u(w-275)$ where $u$ is the unit-ramp or Heaviside function.

Comment: But I think in that case the number of hunted worms would be proportional to $w(t)-275$, not to $w(t)$

Comment: No, why would a multiplication with a factor $0$ or $1$ result in that?

Comment: Because we also multiply by $(w(t)-275)$

Comment: $u(x)$ is a function that takes value $0$ for $x<0$ and value $1$ for $x>0$, with the value at $x=0$ by personal preference, $0$, $\frac12$ and $1$ all having some justification. There is no extra factor, only the argument of this function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102674/discussion-between-prosep-and-lutz-lehmann).